# Disabling chmod for some users

Tags: linux, chmod

In Linux system, assume that there is user 'A' (non-root user who has ssh login permission).

'A' owns an executable file "A.out".

I want to allow 'A' to read/execute "A.out"

However, I don't want 'A' to change permission of "A.out"

as a root user, how can I enforce this?(in Ubuntu server)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only two ways you can enforce this are:

1. Change the file's owner to `root` or another user.
2. Use SELinux/AppArmor/SMACK to deny the chmod usage.

Comment: Just to add, when/if you do change file's owner to root, make sure that "userA" has read-only access to file by being in group-owner group of file.

Comment: @edvinas.me: Or by being in the file's ACL.

Comment: it seems that if the owner of 'A.out' is root and group of 'A.out' is 'A' and if I give the permission of 'A.out' ---r-x---, it works as I want. A can RX the file 'A.out' but cannot change the permission. Am i right?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but isn't it an option to set the file as immutable? (I.e. `chattr +i A.out`). Only superusers can do this and the file will be read-only. The user would still be able to set write permissions but cannot write to the file.